# Bootsfaces checkbox

Tags: jsf, javabeans, bootsfaces

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dropdownView.value}">
<p:ajax update="msgs" listener="#{dropdownView.add}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

In primefaces I am able to call bean method to perform action on click of checkbox with the above code.

But I am unable to call bean method to perform action on click of `selectBooleanCheckbox` in Bootsfaces.
Can anyone please help regarding how to successfully call a bean method which displays message `true` or `false` onclick of `selectBooleancheckbox` in Bootsfaces.

I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
<b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dropdownView.value}" 
           update="msgs" onchange="ajax:ajaxBean.add()" />
```

I am new to bootsfaces. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BootsFaces showcase](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/checkBox.jsf) has an example how to use AJAX with checkboxes. Our example uses `onclick` instead of `onchange`. Other than that, everything seems to be identical. I didn't check that yet, but it's possible `b:checkbox` doesn't support `onchange` (although I don't see why not - we've implemented both events).

By the way, the other approach using `f:ajax` / `p:ajax` and a listener should work, too. But we've added this feature later, so we don't guarantee that the traditional JSF style of AJAX always works with BootsFaces.

Comment: Thankyou so much... Got the output.. Replaced onchange with onclick="ajax:dropdownView.add();"